# Alternative to Windows Explorer that allows easy navigation in identical folder structures

Tags: windows, file-management

Does anyone know a file explorer that supports easy switching in folder structures that are identical except for a base folder?

Let me give an example what I would like to do:

Let's say I am currently at
`C:\Base1\2015\Q1\February\sales\` and I'd like to switch to
`C:\Base5\2015\Q1\February\sales\`.

With standard Windows Explorer I will have to "reenter" all nested folders after I switched to `Base5`. I would like to "just exchange" the base folder and preserve the subsequent nested path.

Is there any alternative that allows such kind of navigation?

Comment: What about one of the many multi-tree pane editors?  One of them could provide what you want.

Comment: In your example, you could simply click into that location bar, and edit the path: Replace the "1" (in "Base1") with the "5", hit `Enter` – et voila :)

Comment: why don't just Alt+D or F4 and edit the address bar directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of very nice "twin-commander" style file managers that will allow you to do just this -- and much more besides:

#### [Double Commander](http://doublecmd.sourceforge.net/)

The main interface (pic from website) looks like this on Windows 7:

[image: Double Commander main interface]

You'll see each "pane" has the path at the top of the listing. If you **right-click** this, it makes the path editable:

[image: path-edit-1]

You can simply replace the `1` in `Base1` with `5` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to change to the other branch.

A single-click on that line gives your recent "history". Note that the `*` (asterisk) in the string of symbols beside where the disk-free space is reported gives you a "favourites" listing, and you can save directories there. So that's *three* fast and simple ways to change directories.

See the website for other features. To sweeten the deal:

- "gratis", open source released under LGPLv2;
- **cross-platform** -- I have used this very happily under both OS X and Ubuntu; but the download figures on Sourceforge show that Windows is by far the most common platform on which it is used.

---

#### [FreeCommander](http://freecommander.com/en/summary/)

The same workflow is also possible with the Windows-only FreeCommander (my main file-manager during my Windows days; I now work mostly on Ubuntu and Mac OS X):

[image: FreeCommander main interface]

There are many other configurations possible (see the website for details). The situation is almost identical to Double Commander, described above; only this time use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to get the "editable" path:

[image: path-edit-2]

And again, there are shortcuts for favourite folders (the "heart-folder" icon) plus directory-history for navigation as well.

(Note that while FreeCommander is "free", it is [not released under an open source license](http://freecommander.com/en/license/).)

Comment: Total Commander will let you do the same, but slightly different: Press Ctrl-Shift-P to get the current folder in the command line box, edit the path as you like, edit `CD ` (that's with trailing space) in front, hit Enter.

Comment: Thanks! It just appeared to me that the same thing (editing the location) would also works in standard windows explorer (at least with the Win7 one). Together with a two-panes solution this is then even more handy and will certainly improve my workflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the tool [Q-Dir](http://www.softwareok.com/?Download=Q-Dir). With this tool you can have views next to each other or above each other. There are also view modes which allows to see more than two locations at once.

[image: Screenshot Q-Dir]
<sup>*Q-Dir* Screenshot (source: [SoftwareOK](http://www.softwareok.com/?Download=Q-Dir); click image for larger variant)</sup>